# Function isn't returning, Swift Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pull data from firebase and put into an array, using the method shown down below. When using the error completion handler like I was suggested, I assign the values of Data to the array locData. The get locdata function is all the way at the bottom.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class SearchSelectVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var locationPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var humidityPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLB: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var humidityLB: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLB: UILabel!

    var locData: [String] = [String]()
    var humidityData : [String] = [String]()
    var dateData : [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //  initPickers()
        humidityPicker.delegate = self
        humidityPicker.dataSource = self
        locationPicker.delegate = self
        locationPicker.dataSource = self
        datePicker.delegate = self
        datePicker.dataSource = self
        //locData = [ "hi" , "hi2 ","hi3","hi4", "hi5", "hi6", "hi7"]
        //dateData = [ "no" , "no2 ","no3","no4", "no5", "no6", "no7"]
        //humidityData = [ "yes" , "yes2 ","yes3","yes4", "yes5", "yes6", "yes7"]
        //datePicker.isHidden = true
        //locationPicker.isHidden = true
        //humidityPicker.isHidden = true
        getLoc(onCompletion: { (data) in
            print(data)
            self.locData = data
        }, onError: { (error) in
        })
        print(locData)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if(pickerView == locationPicker){
            return 1
        }
        else if(pickerView == datePicker){
            return 1
        }
        else if(pickerView == humidityPicker){
            return 1
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (pickerView == locationPicker) {
            return locData.count
        }
        else if (pickerView == humidityPicker){
            return humidityData.count
        }
        else if (pickerView == datePicker) {
            return dateData.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView == locationPicker) {
            return locData[row]
        }
        else if(pickerView == datePicker){
            return dateData[row]
        }
        if(pickerView == humidityPicker){
            return humidityData[row]
        }
        return "thisisbad"
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if(pickerView == locationPicker){
            updateLabelLoc()
            getDate(onCompletion: { (data) in
                print(data)
                self.dateData = data
            }, onError: { (error) in
            })
        }
        else if(pickerView == datePicker){
            updateLabelDate()
            getHumidity(onCompletion: { (data) in
                print(data)
                self.humidityData = data
            }, onError: { (error) in
            })
        }
        else if(pickerView == humidityPicker){
            updateLabelHumidity()
        }
    }
    func updateLabelLoc(){
        let location = locData[locationPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        locationLB.text = location
    }
    func updateLabelDate(){
        let date = dateData[datePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        dateLB.text = date
    }
    func updateLabelHumidity(){
        let humidity = humidityData[datePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        humidityLB.text = humidity
    }
    func getDate(onCompletion: @escaping (Array<String>) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) {
        var data : [String] = []
        let selectedLoc = locationLB.text
        var dateRef: DatabaseReference!
        dateRef = Database.database().reference().child("launch").child((selectedLoc)!)
        dateRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                data.append(key)
                print("date = \(key)")
                print(data)
                onCompletion(data)
            }
        })
    }
    func getLoc(onCompletion: @escaping (Array<String>) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError) -> Void){
        var data : [String] = []
        var locRef: DatabaseReference!
        locRef = Database.database().reference().child("launch")
        locRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                data.append(key)
                print("location = \(key)")
                print(data)
                onCompletion(data)
            }

        })
    }
    func getHumidity(onCompletion: @escaping (Array<String>) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError) -> Void){
        var data : [String] = []
        let selectedLoc = locationLB.text
        let selectedDate = dateLB.text
        var humidityRef: DatabaseReference!
        humidityRef = Database.database().reference().child("launch").child((selectedLoc)!).child((selectedDate)!)
        humidityRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                data.append(key)
                print("humidity = \(key)")
                print(data)
                onCompletion(data)
            }
        })
    }
    func initPicker(onCompletion: @escaping (Array<String>) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError) -> Void){
        humidityPicker.delegate = self
        humidityPicker.dataSource = self
        locationPicker.delegate = self
        locationPicker.dataSource = self
        datePicker.delegate = self
        datePicker.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm assigning it correctly but when I try to print locData, nothing happens. Also, my UIPickerViews aren't showing up when I run the program.

Comment: you should use a completion handler rather a returning an array. you are currently returning the data before it even before any data is appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`observeSingleEvent` is an asynchronous call so you need to make a `completionHandler` on your function `getDate` that will be called when the method is done:

```
func getDate(onCompletion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    var data : [String] = []
    let selectedLoc = locationLB.text
    var dateRef: DatabaseReference!
    dateRef = Database.database().reference().child("launch").child((selectedLoc)!)
    dateRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            data.append(key)
            print("date = \(key)")
            print(data)
            onCompletion(data)
        }
    })
}
```

To call it:

```
getDate(onCompletion: { (data) in
    print(data)
}
```

Comment: @RohanRao, read about that call I don´t think you need the error part so I removed it. Also do `return [String]` instead from your `completionHandler`also it´s not really ok to accept and answer and then remove the accept and update the question. You should ask a new question instead.

Comment: @RohanRao, you probably have 1 question/day

Comment: yea i think so.

Comment: When im calling the function and want to add it to my array would i do something like myArray.append(date)?

Comment: I don´t know the structure but you should append the string date to your array yes.

Comment: When I try to append the value of data, i get the error "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String.'" Would I return a string rather than a  [String]?